Italians will only surrender village after celebrating annual wine festival
I watched this movie long long back, and the movie is quite old.
What I roughly remember is a captain is ordered to capture a village in Italy. The Italian officer in command is only willing to surrender if they are allowed to celebrate their annual village wine festival.
Any idea which movie this is?
EDIT :
It's an English movie, I don't think so it was black & white, but yes old movie, i watched that movie on MGM channel :) Maybe it's a movie of 60's.

Do you have any additional information about it? Like the approximate time frame, or at least when you watched it, was it black-white (wince you say it's quite old), what country it was from, every detail that could help in identifying it, however small and insignificant it may seem to you.

@ChristianRau Edited

I believe this is film called "What did you do in the war, daddy?". It was a war comedy directed by Blake Edwards (who directed Breakfast at Tiffany's along with the original Pink Panther films) and was released in 1966 through United Artists (which later was purchased my MGM, thus why it would be on the MGM channel). 
The entire film concerns Charlie Company trying to capture the village of Valerno, which just wants to have a festival.
